# Vim autocomplete include filenames with supertab

Tags: vim

In vim, does the SuperTab plugin support autocompleting local filenames? For example, In a C++ program, I want to tbe able to type:

`#include "file`<kbd>tab</kbd>

And if there's a file called "fileparser.h" in the local directory, have SuperTab autocomplete to:

`#include "fileparser.h`

With my current config, the only elements in the autocomplete menu are C++ entities like classnames, no filenames.

Comment: You can use `<c-x><c-f>` to do filename completion. I'm not sure how to get super tab to check multiple completion types. `:h compl-filename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the plugin's help:

```
    let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "<c-x><c-u>"

Note: a special value of 'context' is supported which will result in
super tab attempting to use the text preceding the cursor to decide which
type of completion to attempt.  Currently super tab can recognize method
calls or attribute references via '.', '::' or '->', and file path
references containing '/'.

    let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"

    /usr/l<tab>     # will use filename completion
```

So yes, there is filetype completion, but only if the completion base already includes a slash (which is not the case in your example). You can easily modify the plugin to also accept a preceding `#include`, like this (*the third-last line is new*):

```
function! s:ContextText() " {{{
let exclusions = exists('g:SuperTabContextTextFileTypeExclusions') ?
    \ g:SuperTabContextTextFileTypeExclusions : []

if index(exclusions, &ft) == -1
    let curline = getline('.')
    let cnum = col('.')
    let synname = synIDattr(synID(line('.'), cnum - 1, 1), 'name')
    if curline =~ '.*/\w*\%' . cnum . 'c' ||
    \ curline =~ '#include\s.*\%' . cnum . 'c' ||
    \ ((has('win32') || has('win64')) && curline =~ '.*\\\w*\%' . cnum . 'c')
    return "\<c-x>\<c-f>"
```

Alternatively, you can trigger the built-in filetype completion via `<C-x><C-f>`.

Comment: I had to add :endfunction to stop vim from complaining, but even when I added this to my .vimrc, it still wouldn't autocomplete to local filenames in include statements.

Comment: That's not the entire function, and you're supposed to override the existing one in `plugin/supertab.vim` (version 2.0). Sorry if that wasn't clear. Also note that I didn't test my changes, but it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Whoops, I misunderstood. Works when I do this <https://github.com/lorin/supertab/commit/de2e8f1> and set `let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"`